# Setting Heartbeat when connecting to RabbitMQ via Amqplib

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

When connecting to **RabbitMQ** via **amqplib**, the value of the **Heartbeat** parameter cannot be set.

I do this:

```
// NPM Modules
const amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');
const withAutoRecovery = require('amqplib-auto-recovery');

// Application configuration
const config = settings.getConfig();

withAutoRecovery(amqp, {
  onError: (err) => { console.log(err.message); },
  isErrorUnrecoverable: (err) => { console.log(err) }
}).connect(config.rabbitmq, (err, connection) => {
    // If there are connection errors
    if (err) {
        console.error(this.conn_str_amqp);
        console.error('[AMQP] Connection error:', err.message); 
    } else if (connection) {
        // Connection Error Event
        connection.on('error', (err) => {
            if (err.message !== 'Connection closing') {
                console.error('[AMQP] Closing connection', err.message);
            }
        });
        // Error event when you close the connection
        connection.on('close', () => {
            console.error('[AMQP] Closing connection');
        });
        // Hint to user
        console.log('[AMQP] Connected');
    }
});
```

Here **config.rabbitmq** is:

```
{
  protocol: 'amqp',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: 5672,
  username: 'guest',
  password: 'guest',
  locale: 'en_US',
  frameMax: 0x1000,
  heartbeat: 1800,
  vhost: '/',
}
```

I expect to get the **Heartbeat = 1800s** parameter value, in the **UI Managment** window the default value **Heartbeat = 60s** is displayed.

Screenshot:
[image]

I tried to pass another object instead **config.rabbitmq** line (https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html and https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-query-parameters.html) in the format:

```
function getRabbitMQConnectionString() {
    const rabbitmq = config.rabbitmq;
    return `${rabbitmq.protocol}://${rabbitmq.username}:${rabbitmq.password}@${rabbitmq.hostname}:${rabbitmq.port}${encodeURIComponent(rabbitmq.vhost)}?heartbeat=${rabbitmq.heartbeat}`;
}
```

Thus, too, it turned out similar to the above effect.

Tell me, please, how to correctly set the Heartbeat parameter through the Node.js client application on amqplib?

Comment: hi, how did you solve this? thanks in advance

Comment: Hey, i'm also facing with the same problem

Comment: Hi. It seems to me that the problem is in a specific version RabbitMQ. Updated the higher version - it worked.

Answer (score 1):

#### Reason

The reason of getting `heartbeat 60s` in **Management UI** is because the **RabbitMQ** server have default `heartbeat 60s`.

#### Explanation

And during connection creation the minimum of both `client(amqplib)` and `server(RabbitMQ)` `heartbeat` value is taken.

#### Solution

So, to increate the heartbeat value from `amqplib`, we need to have more or equal value set in RabbitMQ configurations

#### Methods to Set heartbeat value for RabbitMQ Server

1. [How to change RabbitMQ Heartbeat without restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56886770/how-to-change-rabbitmq-heartbeat-without-restart)
2. [https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#:~:text=Max%20value%3A%20536870912-,heartbeat,-Value%20representing%20the](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#:%7E:text=Max%20value%3A%20536870912-,heartbeat,-Value%20representing%20the)

#### Reference for more detail

- https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html
- https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I set up the heartbeat to 30 s and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

From RabbitMQ documentation, they suggest not to set the heartbeats high, because it can disable them.
However, I don't know what is shown as 60s heartbeats.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html#disabling